# "Object doesn't support this action" on calling Ajax.autocompleter

Tags: javascript, autocomplete, scriptaculous

I'm trying to use the autocompleter from http://madrobby.github.io/scriptaculous/ajax-autocompleter/

```
  function autoSuggest(inputTagId, divTagId) {

            new Ajax.Autocompleter(inputTagId, divTagId, '/tmptypeaheadservlet', null);
     }
```

But it throws as error "Object doesn't support this action" when the Ajax.Autocompleter is called.

Edit:

Here is how the function is getting called:

```
   onkeypress="autoSuggest('Line_<%=OrderLineCounter%>','autoCompleteMenu_<%=OrderLineCounter%>')"
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try changing `null` with `{}` ? The function needs an empty object, not a `null`.

Also id's should be in quotes: `new Ajax.Autocompleter("autocomplete", "autocomplete_choices", "/url/on/server", {});`

Comment: What about id's in quotes ? `new Ajax.Autocompleter("autocomplete", "autocomplete_choices", "/url/on/server", {});`

Comment: But the function autoSuggest is being passed with inputTagId, divTagId which are in  quotes.

Comment: In your example, they don't.

Comment: Try to hardcode first the id's instead of using erb tags, just in case. Also, I am not quite sure If it's the same to use quotes on the view, so I can't tell. Sometimes things must be setup exactly as requested by plugins/gems etc. and I have spent days to troubleshoot something because I believed "it should work". Just my 2'.

Answer (score 0):

Is back end exception? if back end exception ,you can check the action method parms.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be even calling the servlet.